# Save more than one string to the same internal storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I need to do something like this:

In first `Activity`, I save the first string to the internal storage and in second `Activity` I save the second string to the same internal storage.

I have problem, when I try to save the second string, internal storage always keeps only the last string and previous disappears.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal storage is based on key-value system. So it is normal, that for 1 key, there is only 1 value available. You can append the new value somehow like this:

```
private static final String SETTINGS_NAME = "my_settings.cfg";
private static final String DELIM = ";";

public void settingsAppendValue(Context context, String key, String value)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String actualValue = settings.getString(key, "");

    Editor editor = settings.edit();
    actualValue += (actualValue.length() > 0 ? DELIM : "") + value;
    editor.putString(key, actualValue);
    editor.commit();        
}

public String[] settingsGetValues(Context context, String key)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return settings.getString(key, "").split(DELIM);        
}
```